# How do I sort, filter and sync large Backbone Collections effectively?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for quite a while now, forgive me if I oversaw something.

I am working with a Backbone Collection that's large enough to take some seconds to arrive from the backend. As it is going to grow steadily, I'd like to load it in chunks and paginate the rendered results. There is also a feature to filter the models.

My apporach to getting less at a time from the backend would be to load only the models that are actually shown (filtered) at the moment. E.g. if I am filtering by month, get the models by fetching from `/collection?year=2013&month=08`.

But this means that I have to add backend parameters for all filter options. Also I would need a way to determine if I have already loaded models for some specific filter criteria to prevent loading the same stuff twice.

Do you have any idea how this could be done better?

Comment: Is the lengthy load time due to the number of models in your collection or to the size of individual models. In other words, could you get away with loading a "summary model" for everything in the collection and then request a more detailed model as needed?

Comment: It is because of the length of the collection. I think a "summary model" would not be very much shorter..

Answer (score 0):

I currently use [backbone-pageable](https://github.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable). You definitely need to do optimizations on your backend to reduce the load time.

Comment: I already saw that one. To use this without loading everything I would basically have to use the approach mentioned in my question - implement filtering and sorting in the backend.